# acer R301L doesn't recognize boot usb I made from UNetbootin

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb, asus, unetbootin

Just bought an ASUS R301L, immediately downloaded UBUNTU through UNetbootin using a USB I formatted for the occasion, then restarted, but it goes directly back to windows (cursed be) in stead of booting menu. Tried pushing all the f-buttons, esc, delete, shift, during startup, but to no avail. Don't know how to reach the BIOS of which legends tell me. SOS.

Answer (score 0):

Hold the F2 key until the BIOS screen appears. Also, if you don't want to do that, go to the Boot Menu.

Source: http://www.asus.com/my/support/FAQ/1008829/

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1 :**

Unetbootin is known to not create the media properly.
Use the diskpart tool which is included in Windows OS.

Open **command prompt as administrator** and execute:

```
diskpart
list disk  
select disk *  
clean  
create partition primary  
active  
format fs=fat32 quick  
assign letter=**
```

Note : * = number of USB drive | ** = select a free drive letter
Mount the ISO file and copy all the content to the USB drive.

**Step 2 :**

Disable hibernation mode and Fast startup in Windows.
Open **command prompt as administrator** and execute :

```
powercfg /h off
```

Open the legacy version of the Windows Control Panel (not the modern one).
Select **Power Settings**, enable **show hidden settings** and uncheck Fast Boot.

After having done this, **shutdown** the computer completely, do NOT reboot.
Start the computer and select the Ubuntu USB install media in BIOS to boot.